# The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, xcode8

I'm getting error while trying to run my app*. Xcode says "**The request to open "com.arm-tab.firebase-test" failed.** The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified."
Restarting simulator doesn't fix this.

*
i've created simple test project for testing Firebase, added podfile with Firebase/Auth, installed that pod, added [FIRApp configure] message in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: I get this error sometimes in my Jenkins UI tests when I run on simulator (xcodebuild).

Comment: creating new project solved this

Comment: check your scheme settings and make sure all empty settings are unchecked. i ran into this issue trying to disable the nw_ logging spam.

Comment: @AndrewAnthonyGerst this should be an answer so it can be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

Check your scheme settings and make sure all empty settings are unchecked. I ran into this issue trying to disable the `nw_` logging spam.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 Xcode workspaces open. I closed one. Error stopped. App ran fine in simulator thereafter.

More details: *Workspace A* contained *Swift Framework X* I was creating. *Workspace B* contained *App Z* that used *Swift Framework X*. Workspaces were in separate folders. *Workspace B* pulled in *Swift Framework X* via Carthage and Git. No local file system link between workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on my simulators while messing with Xcode 12.4 and 12.5.

I think the issue was that I was trying to run my app on a simulator which was installed by the other version of xcode.

I resolved the issue by clearing out their content and restarting the simulators. I get the feeling that just restarting would of done the trick, but doing both resolved my issue.