# The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, cordova

im using the latest Cordova, XCode and Mac OSX Sierra

i am unable to build the sample project on any old devices in the simulator (iPhone 5 or less)

the error im getting isnt very helpful because the console.log file DOESNT EXIST!

any ideas at all?

An error was encountered processing the command

> > (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1): The request to
> >     open "com.hestor.nasmob" failed. The request was denied by service
> >     delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.
>
> logPath: /Developer/Cordova/NASMob/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log

Simon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645824/the-request-was-denied-by-service-delegate-sbmainworkspace)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcode 8 error denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495620/xcode-8-error-denied-by-service-delegate-sbmainworkspace)

Answer (score 6):

Check your scheme settings and make sure all empty settings are unchecked.
After doing this restart Xcode and simulator.

If it doesn't work try to restart the system.

Comment: I have to quit the simulator and let Xcode start it up to debug or the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, same situation here. After nothing of scheme settings, reinstall, reboot etc helped, the only thing helped for me:

Create a simulator for iPhone5s and iOS 9.3 (instead of iOS 10.3). 
Then advice project to use iOS 9.3.

Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 0):

**Quit** the **simulator**, and re-run it again.

It works fine.